# how to fix "Cannot read property 'setState' of null"

Tags: reactjs, state, lifecycle, setstate

i try to update state with setState in a for loop in componentDidMount but every time i get this error  "Cannot read property 'setState' of null"

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../../../Config'
import * as firebase from  'firebase';
import './Header.scss'
class MessageBox extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      users:[],
}
    this.setState= this.setState.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount(){

   firebase.database()
    .ref("Users")
    .on('value', gotData , errData);
    function gotData (data) {
      var users = data.val();
      console.log(users ,"uuuuuuuuuuuu")
      var keys=Object.keys(users);
      console.log(keys,"keys")
      for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i];
        var myuser = (users[k]);
           this.setState({users: myuser});
        console.log(myuser,'newUser')
        console.log(myuser.username,"myuserName")
        console.log(myuser.id,"myuserId")
        console.log(myuser.imageURL,"myuserImage")
```

Comment: This is kinda bad practice.. since each time you fire setState you actualy update the component. It will be better if you will create the object that you need and after the loop apply it to the state.

Comment: if i call my object after the loop he render just the last item

Comment: this is already what happens now, isn't it? any way. you could create an array object. apply all the users to it and then just fire setState with the array.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
function gotData (data) {
```

use this

```
 gotData=()=>{//your code;
 }
```

as in react 'this' refer to cur function when defined by old syntax,you can also bind gotData like in constructor

```
this.gotData=this.gotData.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep your `this.setState(...)` outside of `firebase.database()` but inside of `componentDidMount(){...}`

2) If you want to store all of your **`myuser`** make a list of all myuser and put it into setState like this way **`this.setState({ users: listOfMyUser})`**

Hopefully it will solve your problem